# Function that extracts email-adresses from strings given in an assert and gives them in a list

Tags: python, regex

Before I go on, there are many questions previously asked *like* this one but I none I have found exactly like this.

I want to write a function that correctly interprets these results and give the outputs shown

```
assert get_mail("") == []
assert get_mail("rektor@kth.se") == ["rektor@kth.se"]
assert get_mail("Private mail is foo@gmail.com work mail is bar@corp.com.") == ["foo@gmail.com", "bar@corp.com"]
```

that is it extracts the email adresses from a string given to the function and returns them in a list.
What I have come up with is this

```
import re  
def get_mail(text):
    email_list = []
    s = text
    match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)
    email_list.append(match)
    return email_list
```

my reasoning is this: I start with an empty list where the adresses should later be appended. I say that the text inside the get_mail() is s and then to scan s to only find email adresses and return the appended list, but obviously something is wrong or missing.

Comment: You don't have to append, re.findall will return the list. https://ideone.com/4VBbR7

Comment: Oh ok! So email_list.append(match) can be removed then?

Comment: Yes, you can read more about re.findall [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: I got it working! I replaced email_list.append(match) with print(match) and all asserts are shown correctly. Thank you!

Comment: I think you can just `return re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)`

Comment: The output is given with ' right now i.e. ['rektor@kth.se'] how can I make them " instead?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Do you know?

Comment: I can not immediately find why that is or if it is possible to change that

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code. The first is that you have overcomplicated your function and its returning a list within a list. Therefore making the assertion fail. Instead, a simple get_mail() function like the one below will fix your second assertion error:

```
def get_mail(text):
    match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)
    return match
```

The second problem, is that your e-mail regex pattern is not optimal, and in your third assertion test it extracts:

```
['foo@gmail.com', 'bar@corp.com.']
```

Which is not the same as what you want:

```
['foo@gmail.com', 'bar@corp.com']
```

You see the difference? Is that 1 dot at the end of 'bar@corp.com.' that's causing the problem. Its not recommended that you write your own email regex pattern, but that you find an optimum one online instead. That will solve your 3rd assertion error.